# Not showing image icon of <img> tag in firefox and chrome while showing in IE browser using html

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have written html code in JSP file and it is for showing icon link. It is successfully running in IE browser but not showing image icon in chrome and Firefox browser and even no adblocker is there in my browsers.

```html
<table border="1" width="90%" class="buttons">
  <tr>
    <td width="25%"><a href="#">PROJECT</a>
    </td>
    <td width="25%">
      <a href="CrunchifyServlet">
        <img height="20px" src="C://Users//Downloads//Start-icon.png">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image URL points to a resource which ist only accessible for browsers if they have permission to read the file system. Also no one but yourself will have access to this URL.

Better change the absolute URL…

`<img height="20px" src="C://Users//Downloads//Start-icon.png">`

into a relative one:

`<img height="20px" src="./YOUR-PATH-HERE/Start-icon.png">`

This also helps you in case you want to copy your files to another server.

Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL for more information on URLs.

Comment: Yes I have tried that ./C:/Users//Downloads/Start-icon.png but it is not showing the image in IE too.

Comment: Finally I got the answers. I have copied the image icon i.e. Start-icon.png in Web content folder and then given the name only like 
    <img height="20px" src="Start-icon.png"></a></td>
and it worked, also I tried putting full http URL of project after copying image in that and that also worked like 
    <img height="20px" src="http://localhost:8080/Newproject/Start-icon.png"></a></td>.

Thanks